# What is the popular name for a packet of pre-washed salad leaves?

Tags: word-choice

These come in various types and are pre-washed in packets; crisp iceberg lettuce leaves (which I prefer), rocket, plain leaves which look like things cows would chew, plus more exciting mixtures including other vegetables, shredded carrot, nuts etc.

These seem to be replacing the purchase of whole lettuces in some households.

What I am interested to know is what do people call them?

What do you write on the shopping list; packet-salad; bag of leaves; packet lettuce; bag of greens; or what? We have not reached any settled nomenclature in our household, which sometimes leads to confusion.

I am interested in how they are known generically?

Comment: "Pre-washed" salad,  ["ready-to-eat" salad](http://www.sainsburys.co.uk/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/gb/groceries/fruit-veg/ready-to-eat-salad-199711-44?langId=44&storeId=10151&krypto=ljYCzqNa6odW7VknC98L91zxKdi55no3ZxLt51gfLPKHWFkd892WZLfakFSc4w87zF%2BXLGaSSH7f%0AXvDM1ElXDcD9wmzQmVxgUjcwDCMYlhZ1XbC4Cqq2OkEppvYgYXII&ddkey=http:gb/groceries/fruit-veg/ready-to-eat-salad-199711-44#langId=44&storeId=10151&catalogId=10122&categoryId=199711&parent_category_rn=12518&top_category=12518&pageSize=30&orderBy=FAVOURITES_FIRST&searchTerm=&beginIndex=0)? I admit I was thinking about this the other day.

Answer (score 4):

I would call it *bagged salad*. And it seems like the usage is common:

[Seen At 11: Should You Rewash ‘Prewashed’ Bagged Salads?](http://newyork.cbslocal.com/2014/02/26/seen-at-11-should-you-rewash-prewashed-bagged-salads/)

[Bagged Salad Mix May Be Culprit Behind Stomach Bug Outbreak, Health Officials Say](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/07/31/bagged-salad_n_3683949.html)

[Food waste: Tesco reveals most bagged salad and half its bread is thrown out](http://www.theguardian.com/business/2013/oct/21/food-waste-tesco-reveals-most-bagged-salad-and-half-its-bread-is-thrown-out)

Answer (score 1):

Some rudimentary research reveals...

[Tesco](http://www.tesco.com/groceries/Product/Search/?searchBox=salad%20leaves) — Salad Bag:

[image: Tesco website]

[Sainsbury](http://www.sainsburys.co.uk/shop/gb/groceries/fruit-veg/fresh-salad-prepared-ready-to-eat#langId=44&storeId=10151&catalogId=10122&categoryId=13297&parent_category_rn=12518&top_category=12518&pageSize=30&orderBy=FAVOURITES_FIRST&searchTerm=&beginIndex=0) — Prepared Salad:

[image: Sainsbury website]

[Asda](http://groceries.asda.com/asda-webstore/landing/home.shtml?cmpid=ahc-_-ghs-d1-_-asdacom-dsk-_-hp#/shelf/910000976506/1/so_false) — Prepared Salad:

[image: Asda website]

[Morrisons](http://groceries.morrisons.com/webshop/getCategories.do?tags=|105651|104268|105544|104744&Asidebar=3) — Salad Bag:

[image: Morrisons website]

So there doesn't appear to be much of a consensus amongst major British supermarkets. ***Salad bag*** or ***bagged salad*** is probably more descriptive than "prepared" for a shopping list, though.

Comment: I am not happy with the term 'salad'. The latter is usually a term which includes other ingredients not normally found in 'bagged salad' e.g. cucumber, tomatoes, spring onions etc. I'm prepared to recognise it as 'salad' if it contains a range of ingredients, nuts, carrot etc., but if it is simply comprised of leaves it seems presumptuous to call it 'salad'.

Comment: @WS2 wouldn't the more precise term be "mixed salad" for a salad that contains other ingredients than salad leaves? Green salad suggests only the leafed variety, no room for Treviso salad or chicory here. But *salad* embraces all varieties without prejudice. It's a very politically correct term :)